# Trigger downstream jobs depending upon the some input parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement to trigger a job depending upon some condition. Let’s say I have job J1,j2,J3 and J4

The J1 executes and depending upon the input parameter x on job J1 it should trigger either J2 or J3. If the x is 1 it should trigger J2 and if the x is 2 it should trigger J3.

somewhat like below flow chart

```
                                            J1 
                                    x=1  /   \  x=2 
                                          /     \ 
                                         J2      J3
```

I want to do this as part of Post build action, that means once Job J1 build is success I want to trigger the job dynamically based on input parameter.

I tried Conditional step plugin – but that’s not helping with this scenario because I can’t have condition step plugin in Post  build action step.  Can someone suggest what’s the best approach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin and use its regex functionality to check the value of x.